# Is direct-to-heroku-client compatible with latest heroku API jar?

Tags: java, heroku

I've already configured my project to use direct-to-heroku-client.jar (https://github.com/heroku/direct-to-heroku-client-java) with heroku-api-0.24.jar and
when I test deploy of WAR artifact - it says "Failed to deploy 'war-test-artifact': com.herokuapp.directto.client.DeploymentException: Deploy not accepted".
I investigated that within direct-to-heroku-client API artifact might be uploaded to https://direct-to.herokuapp.com:443/direct during deploying, but it does not happened. So, I just want to know, if 
https://direct-to.herokuapp.com:443/direct will be support soon somehow or not and is the direct-to-heroku-client relevant to heroku API v3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That project is deprecated, and not supported (I updated the docs to reflect this).

Instead, you should be using either:

- [Heroku Maven plugin](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java-applications-with-the-heroku-maven-plugin)
- [Heroku Deploy CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment#deployment-with-the-heroku-cli)

For more information, see the [Heroku Dev Center article on WAR Deployment](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment).

Comment: Thanks a lot  for quick response!